# Why does the SwiftUI "Form" cause my button to go to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form

I want to create a view that has a form with a button below it. If I include a form and a button, the button goes to the bottom of the screen.

Without Form Element
[image]

With Form Element
[image]

Is this just a SwiftUI bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
//
//  TestFile.swift
//  searchparty
//
//  Created by Me
//

import SwiftUI

struct TestFile: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form{
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            
            Button("Button") {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestFile_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestFile()
    }
}
```

Comment: Expected behavior. Form is a ScrollView and takes all available vertical space.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If that is the expected behavior, then how am I supposed to achieve the results I am looking for? If I put the button inside of the form, the button looks weird because it is surrounded by the white rounded square.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it’s a limitation of SwiftUI right now. Maybe someone else will have a workaround.

Comment: I am not in front of a computer right now, but you might try setting the button as a footer to an empty Section

Comment: That worked! Thank you jdpdx! Still seems a bit hacky, but it will do!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An empty `Section` with a `footer` will do the job, although you'll want to explicitly set the font, or else the `footer` will change it based on the form footer environment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Entry")
            
            Section(footer:
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                Text("My button")
                                    .font(.system(.body))
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
            ) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```